# Cross-platform, safe to use command line string separator

Tags: python, shell, command-line, cross-platform, separator

For a new feature in `PyInstaller`, we need a command line option receiving a string with any separator in it. Here's the discussion: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/1990.

Example:

```
pyinstaller --add-data="file.txt?dir"
```

`?` is the separator here, this should be another character. **It's not guaranteed, that the string is quoted!**

We've thought about `; : > < | *` and so on, but we can't figure out what character would be save to use, without side effects and platform independent (and hopefully not allowed in paths). `>` e.g will redirect stdout, `;` is the command separator on POSIX ect.

Any ideas what character we can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The real problem and its solution

Your question is an instance of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/238706) to some extent. A red herring at least.

As I show below, no ideal path delimiters exist, and therefore **you have to pass that information in separate command-line options**, if you really insist on supporting arbitrarily crazy paths. It is up to the users, then, to escape their weird characters in paths when calling your program.

## No ideal path delimiters exists

Unix paths can contain any characters except ASCII NUL (`\0`). Path components (file names) are not allowed to contain slash (`/`). Anything else is OK, [according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_170).

Therefore, you picked too tight constraints. No ideal solution to your problem exists even on Unix, completely ignoring the portability issue.

## Good path delimiters

You have to put some **“common sense” constraints on paths**, e.g. that [they will not contain semicolon on Windows and colon on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445215/2157640). This combination is quite natural, intuitive and easy to read, by the way, because these characters are [path separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) for these systems.

Let’s find if you can reserve just one character that may never occur in a path. Will the set of constraints be satisfiable then?

If you list non-alphanumeric printable ASCII characters and remove those with special meaning for Unix shell and those used in paths even by sane people (_, -, etc.), you can pick a reasonable path delimiter:

```sh
LC_ALL=C
awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) printf "%c\n", ARGV[i]; }' {1..127} |
    grep '^[[:print:]]$' |
    grep '^[^][*?~$`"'\''&|#\<>(){}!;/[:alnum:] ._-]$'
```

<sup>ASCII is 0..127, but 0 is excluded as it causes trouble with the text-oriented utilities. Bash specials are filtered out, too.</sup>

The resulting set contains just seven characters, though: `%+,:=@^`

Aaah, percent (`%`) and caret (`^`) unfortunately have special meaning in `cmd.exe` and colon (`:`) in Windows paths. Only four remaining: `+,=@`

Either you pick one of those, or you assume they are inconvenient and you revise the list of specials to pick different character for different systems (e.g. the colon and semicolon compromise you have suggested), which relaxes the portability constraint a bit. Or maybe the tilde (`~`) is not that special in shell as it is expanded to home directory path only at shell word start. Or maybe you do not want a separator character, but separator string – you can guess that very few files have `@@@` in their names.

Comment: Wow, Thanks for that answer! We'll discuss that again and I'll come back to you if there are questions left :)

Comment: Ok, we finally use ; and :

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for us was using a platform depependent separator:

- Windows: `;`
- Unix: `:`

A bit tricky to document, but a clean and safe solution.

Comment: This is the scheme used in PATH environment variable.

Comment: This is wrong. unix file names CAN include a `:` in fact paths can include anything but 0x00.

Comment: @swa66 - Oh, I see! So we have to live with the fact that unix paths can contain any character except `/` and `0x00`?

Comment: On unix there is "special" meaning to `:` in eg. a PATH variable. Users that will insist on using a `:` will also be smart enough to know they might have to quote/escape it. Just document how to do that in your man page and they'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @ and \ for escaping :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer! @ seems to be an idea, we'll think about it :)

Comment: `@` is allowed in Windows and Unix filenames, so this is no good solution. We decided to use a platform dependent separator, `;` on Windows and `:` on Unix.

Comment: Unix paths may safely contain colon, @linusg. Try running `touch a:b` on Linux. If the file `a:b` does not exist, it will create it. You can remove it by `rm a:b`. Actually, in a project I contribute to, we use `@` instead of slash if we want to store a path in a file name. It is used in a hack that allows tracking of symlinks in Gnu Make.

Comment: @Palec - So what would you recommend? using `:` or `@` and just hoping that nobody has a colon in a path?

Comment: Your solution with `;` on Windows and `:` on Linux makes sense and is quite intuitive, easy to read. I just wanted to point out that no ideal solution exists and you always have to impose constraints on which path are “sane and supported”.